# Animate div from left to right and then from right to left

Tags: javascript, animation, dom

I am watching this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0

The speaker talks about JS tasks and the DOM rendering. He gives the following example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Task</title>

    <style>
      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      .box {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: pink;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="box"></div>

    <script>
      var box = document.querySelector(".box");

      box.addEventListener("click", () => {
        box.style.transform = "translateX(500px)";
        box.style.transition = "transform 1s ease-in-out";
        box.style.transform = "translateX(250px)";
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And tries to animate the object (on click event) from position 0 to position 500px, and then from 500px to 250px. In other words, from left to right, and from right to the middle.

He uses the following code:

```
var box = document.querySelector(".box");
box.addEventListener("click", () => {
  box.style.transform = "translateX(500px)";
  box.style.transition = "transform 1s ease-in-out";
  box.style.transform = "translateX(250px)";
});
```

Then he explained why it didn't work as expected - because the browser would do all the calculations before rendering/performing the animation. All good here.

However, he says that he solves the issue by wrapping the last `box.style.transform = "translateX(250px)";` into a double (nested) `requestAnimationFrame()` call. When I tried to do that, it did the **exact same thing as before**. It didn't work. Here is the code:

```
box.style.transform = "translateX(500px)";
box.style.transition = "transform 1s ease-in-out";
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    box.style.transform = "translateX(250px)";
  });
});
```

What am I missing here? How to make the browser first perform the transform operation to 500px, and then transform it back to 250px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a mistake in the video.

This is the correct piece of code:

```
box.addEventListener("click", () => {
  box.style.transform = "translateX(500px)";

  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      box.style.transition = "transform 1s ease-in-out";
      box.style.transform = "translateX(250px)";
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one setTimeout in the second statement else both statement with executes one by one very fast so did not get it the actual you want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Task</title>

    <style>
      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      .box {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: pink;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="box"></div>

    <script>
      var box = document.querySelector(".box");

      box.addEventListener("click", () => {
        box.style.transform = "translateX(500px)";
        box.style.transition = "transform 1s ease-in-out";
        setTimeout(function(){
        box.style.transform = "translateX(250px)";
        },1000);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

last statement,

Comment: The speaker said to **avoid** setTimeout for UI operations.

Comment: There needs some delay between those transform statement so both statements execute one after another.
Either needs to apply some animation to get back it after some time.

Comment: If you're interested, watch the talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0. I think the `setTimeout()` in our case is not necessary.

Comment: Okay let me watch

Comment: Yes. I figured it out. I will add the answer.

Comment: Yes please I would wait for this, I was also trying to figure out it but just got busy with some other work.

Comment: Find my answer attached

Comment: Thank for updating me as well